# Revit family attribute data to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, multipatch, bim, revit

I am working on a BIM/GIS project where I need to convert revit models into GIS. I used the FME export and chose the 2*3 coordinate view to export to ifc file, then in ArcScene, I use quick import to convert ifc to multipatch. As a result I get the model sorted in revit family, such as wall, column, slab, etc in multipatch form. The 3D model turn to be fine, but there are extra tables attached to each family and I found much of the data in there was lost. I wonder if this is the problem with exporting ifc in revit or the problem with exporting to multipatch in GIS. (I have pics below to specify)

[image]

As you can see in here, lots of data in the family is lost. For example in the door lining properties, there are null values.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IFC4 instead of the default IFC2X3. New IFC4X3 standard includes more specs.